# Performance Issues with My GCP Instance Running X-Plane 11

Tags: google-cloud-platform, xplane

I am currently a user of Google Cloud Platform, and I recently created an instance to run the flight simulator X-Plane 11. Unfortunately, I am experiencing performance issues with my instance, and I am not achieving the expected results despite selecting a more powerful configuration.

The recommended specifications by X-Plane 11 for an optimal gaming experience are as follows:

```
CPU: Intel Core i5 6600K at 3.5 GHz or faster
RAM: 16 GB RAM
GPU: DirectX 12-capable video card from NVIDIA or AMD with 4 GB VRAM
Storage: 65 GB of available disk space
Network: High-speed internet connection
```

I have taken these specifications into account and configured my GCP instance with more powerful resources, including a high-performance CPU, sufficient RAM, and an advanced GPU. However, I am still encountering prolonged lags and automatic application closures due to memory-related issues.

I am seeking assistance to understand the reasons behind these performance problems and to discover how to improve the gaming experience for smooth gameplay in accordance with X-Plane 11's recommended specifications.

Would it be possible for you to help me resolve this issue? If you have any suggestions regarding the configuration of my GCP instance, tips to optimize X-Plane 11's performance, or recommendations for best practices on running a flight simulator in a cloud environment, I would be extremely grateful to hear them.

Thank you sincerely for your assistance and support in resolving this matter.

Best regards,
Captain_LASS

Unfortunately, I am experiencing performance issues with my instance, and I am not achieving the expected results despite selecting a more powerful configuration.

Comment: What did you configure in the cloud? You just state `with more powerful resources` but without the actual details. You state `an advanced GPU`. Are you sure? New GCP customers require a GPU increase quota request. Your desktop specs probably require the `g2-standard-8` VM (CPU core requirements) or higher at a cost of $623 per month not including the bandwidth to transfer the video stream. Sort of expensive to play video games.